# How do I debug the application of arguments to my function in the Clojure Compiler?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, clojure, compiler-construction

My purpose is to debug the Clojure Compiler to understand more about it. (My project code is an aid to this purpose.).

I've got both the [Clojure Compiler source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure) and my project `test` set up in my IntelliJ IDE. 
[image]

I've got the the `clojure` project as the primary project, and the `test` project is on the classpath. 
[image]

I'm triggering the Clojure REPL in the debugger by running the `clojure.main` class in the `clojure` project. 
[image]

My `test` project has the following source in the `test.core` `core.clj` file:

```
(ns test.core
  (:gen-class))

(deftype SquarePeg [width length])

(deftype RoundHole [radius])

(def square-peg (SquarePeg. 5 50))

(defn insert-peg [^test.core.RoundHole peg]
    (println "insert-peg inserted with: " peg))

(defn -main
  "Insert a square peg in a round hole"
  [& args]
    (insert-peg square-peg)
  (println "Done."))
```

I've set the following breakpoints:

- [`Compiler.java` L4709](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L4709) (Handling vars when emitting values)
- [`AFn.java` L154](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/AFn.java#L154) (Invoking a function with a single argument)

[image]

Now what I'm doing is pasting in the following function invocation into the REPL after I've switched the breakpoints on:

```
(insert-peg square-peg)
```

[image]

Now what I see is that the `println` (as `pr`) in the code above runs through the `AFn.java` single arg invoke, but the call to `insert-peg` does not. (This is what I want to debug).

[image]

(First breakpoint tripped after breakpoints switched on).

[image]

I do see the declarations of `insert-peg` and `square-peg` running through the emit code in the `Compiler.java` - but what I'm looking for is the *function application*. I want to see `square-peg` be applied to `insert-peg` running in the compiler code in the debugger. (Perhaps I'm missing a breakpoint, or looking in the wrong place).

**Assumptions:**

- I don't switch the breakpoints on, until after the REPL has loaded, and I've pasted the code into the REPL running in the IDE console.

My question is: **How do I debug the application of arguments to my function in the Clojure Compiler?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was the function [`InvokeExpr(...)`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L3636) in [`Compiler.java`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L3636).

In particular the [`VarExpr`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L3636) section.